# WSO2 API Manager: When subscribed on a webservice, how to obtain the WSDL?

Tags: soapui, wso2

I have published a `webservice` on `WSO2` API Manager. We subscribed to the service, generated the API key.

Is it possible to obtain the `WSDL` with `SOAPUI`?

How can we use the "Bearer " within SoapUI to generate the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved, by adding the 'Bearer" into the HTTP request in SOAP UI. Click on the header-request tab in SoapUI, add the Bearer with the generated key and the request works.